# How do I simplify this div loop

Tags: css

How do I simplify a div design like this? Angular/Jquery solutions are fine. This is a div filter that goes on top of a movie. Also, should this be simplified or leave it as is?

```
        <div id="filter">
            <div id="row1">
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row2">
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row3">
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row4">
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="row5">
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
                <div class="filgrey"></div>
                <div class="filblack"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yv5qe2gv/

Comment: Take a look at patterned linear gradients: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#checkerboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) like this:

```
.row {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(24,24,24,.6),
      rgba(24,24,24,.6) 15%,
      rgba(10,10,10,.6) 15%,
      rgba(10,10,10,.6) 30%
    );
}
```

And simplify your html to just the `row` elements:

```css
#filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh
}
.row {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(24, 24, 24, .6), rgba(24, 24, 24, .6) 15%, rgba(10, 10, 10, .6) 15%, rgba(10, 10, 10, .6) 30%);
}
.row:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(10, 10, 10, .6), rgba(10, 10, 10, .6) 15%, rgba(24, 24, 24, .6) 15%, rgba(24, 24, 24, .6) 30%);
}
```

```html
<div id="filter">
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

#### <sub>[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv5qe2gv/3/)</sub>

---

Note this will work in chrome for crossbrowser support check [CanIuse](http://caniuse%20linear%20gradient) and [CSSTricks](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)

---

**Edit**

Thanks to this [link with the work of Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#checkerboard) you can simply to just one container.

```
#filter {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.3)), linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.3) 75%, rgba(0,0,0,.3));
    background-size:180px 180px;
    background-position:0 0, 90px 90px
}
```

The only issue is you need a fixed value for the squares.

#### <sub>[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv5qe2gv/4/)</sub>

Comment: Specifying a background-size and position will let you simply repeat this as many times as necessary with only one row div.

Comment: Yep @David I'm working on a solution to just CSS the filter ID :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an angular repeat directive.

```
    <div id="filter">
        <div id="row{{index}}" ng-repeat="index in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]">
            <div class="filblack"></div>
            <div class="filgrey"></div>
            <div class="filblack"></div>
            <div class="filgrey"></div>
            <div class="filblack"></div>
            <div class="filgrey"></div>
            <div class="filblack"></div>
            <div class="filgrey"></div>
            <div class="filblack"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm not positive if you can template the index variable into the ID like that, but are those ID's even important? Also, you can probably create directives to further whittle down the grey/black repeat. Like an even/odd kind of thing.

Comment: After reviewing your CSS, you should DEFINITELY get rid of the IDs and replace them with a single class.

Answer (score 1):

How about this Angular approach (may need tweaking around the black/gray order)

```
<div id="filter">
  <div id="row{{x}}" ng-repeat="x in range(1,5)">
    <div class='fill{{(x+y) % 2 == 0 ? "black" : "gray"}}' ng-repeat="y in range(1,9)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by div loop? I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but you want to reduce your markup, right?

You could start by removing the class names on the inner `div`s in favour of `:nth-child( odd )` and `:nth-child( even )`.

This could be your new markup:

```
<div id="filter">
    <div id="row1">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row2">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row3">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row4">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="row5">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Html :

```
<div id="filter"></div>
```

Jquery :

```
var blackSquare = '<div class="filblack"></div>'
var whiteSquare = '<div class="filgrey"></div>'

for(k=0; k<8; k++)
{
    $('#filter').append('<div id="row'+k+'">');

    for(j=0;j<8; j++)
    {                
       if( ((j+k) % 2) == 0)
       {
           $('#row'+k).append(blackSquare);
       }
       else
       {
           $('#row'+k).append(whiteSquare);
       }
    }   

   $('#filter').append(' </div>');
}
```